# Starting with 3d objects

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, opengl, 3d

I have just started with C++ and would like to program and little with 3d objects. Now I could use C++ or Objective C it doesnt matter.

What books are good with 3d objects?

I want to load a 3d object/file created by a 3d application, and then manipulate the 3d object.

Move it on the screen, rotate it etc.

Where is a good place to start to learn this? A book, tutorials etc.

Answer (score 2):

[Lesson 31](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=31) on [gamedev.net](http://nehe.gamedev.net/) should get you started.

Comment: Beware that NeHe tutorials are badly outdated and teach functionality that has long been deprecated or removed from OpenGL.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine, true, it was written before shaders became mainstream, but the 3D model structures did not change as much :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty nice site with 3d engine tutorials: http://www.spacesimulator.net/wiki/index.php/3d_Engine_Programming_Tutorials

Answer (score 1):

> I have just started with C++

Woah there, have you done any C programming? In order to get anywhere (besides stuck!) in OpenGL, you really need to know C well, since OpenGL is written in C. At the very least you need to know all about pointers, functions, and arrays.

I'd also suggest getting started with 2D objects, and then going to 3D. There really isn't any difference with OpenGL. To render a 2D object, you render the same exact way as a 3D object, but you give every object the same z (depth) value.

Although most of these are deprecated, I'd suggest starting by learning Immediate Mode, moving towards Display Lists, then Vertex Arrays, and finally Vertex Buffer Objects and Index Buffer Objects. These are all different methods of how the GPU gets your vertex/color/texture information, and they all vary in speed.

Comment: Unless you need to target OpenGL 1.x (e.g. running on Intel IGP hardware is required), it would be best to skip display lists.  In many ways immediate mode leads to understanding VBOs better, but knowledge of display lists just isn't applicable to OpenGL 3+.

Comment: Thanks. I can program in C and Objective C, just started with C++. I found this http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html which seems to cover what I want. OpenGL ES as learning the pipeline and some extras from opengl is not supported in ES.